# Http Trigger Not Scaling up using Osiris Keda

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am trying to deploy an HTTP Trigger to keda. I have installed Osiris components for the same. It helped me to scale to zero when no request is coming, but it is not scaling up from 1 instance. I have removed all replica-constraints from deploy.yaml file still no effects.

1. Using AKS Cluster with 3 node
2. Installed Keda and Osiris components using Core Tools install

I expect the nodes to be scaled up when doing a load test for 100 users. But it always show 1 instance.Please help me if anybody have tried it.